addNotificationResponseReceivedListener not getting triggered after push/scheduled notification is clicked
Minimal reproducible example https://snack.expo.dev/@sushil_qeeper/push-notifications
What platform(s) does this occur on? iOS
Where did you reproduce the issue? in a development build
Summary
Followed the instructions to setup notifications or just open the snack. Click on send the notification button a notification will show up on the actual device; click on that notification.
Expected behavior
An alert should show up with a title of: "addNotificationResponseReceivedListener"
Actual behavior
nothing happens.
Result of npx expo-env-info:
System:
  OS: macOS 14.4.1
  Shell: 5.9 - /bin/zsh
Binaries:
  Node: 22.8.0 - /opt/homebrew/bin/node
  Yarn: 1.22.19 - ~/.yarn/bin/yarn
  npm: 10.8.2 - /opt/homebrew/bin/npm
Managers:
  CocoaPods: 1.15.2 - /opt/homebrew/bin/pod
SDKs:
  iOS SDK:
    Platforms: DriverKit 23.5, iOS 17.5, macOS 14.5, tvOS 17.5, visionOS 1.2, watchOS 10.5
IDEs:
  Xcode: 15.4/15F31d - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
npmPackages:
  @expo/metro-config: ^0.18.11 => 0.18.11 
  expo: ~51.0.31 => 51.0.32 
  react: 18.2.0 => 18.2.0 
  react-native: 0.74.5 => 0.74.5 
npmGlobalPackages:
  eas-cli: 7.2.0
  expo-cli: 6.3.10
Expo Workflow: bare

I want to add a push notification handler to my Expo/React Native app. Every time someone clicks a notification, I want them to open the article associated with that notification through a deep link. However, my notification handler is never being triggered. I know because I am running a basic notification handler that just logs the notification, but it's not getting triggered. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!
